# Jquery validation using bind not working

Tags: jquery, event-handling, locale

I am working on validation of input field in an application that supports multiple languages.
I have bind input events to call the function that converts full width chars to half width chars (for Chinese) and also another function that checks the range between which the numbers shall be valid for the input field.
Code for full-width to half-width conversion:

```
$('.half_width').bind("input",function() {
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace( /[\uff01-\uff5e]/g, function(ch){ return String.fromCharCode(ch.charCodeAt(0) - 0xfee0); }) );
        });
```

Code for validating range within which the integer shall lie

```
$('#input_box').bind('input', function (event) {
        var number = $(this).val();
        var retval = ValidateifDigit(number,event,4);
        return retval;
    });

    $('#input_box').bind('input', function (event) {
        var number = $(this).val();
        var obj = new Object();
        obj.integerDigits = 3;
        obj.lowerLimit = 8;
        obj.upperLimit = 960;
        alert("ma");
        var retval = self.validateNumber (obj, number);
        if(retval==false){
            $('#parent_div').css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('#input_box').parent().addClass('error');
        } else{
            $('#parent_div').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $('#input_box').parent().removeClass('error');
        }
        viewModel.exposureInput().tubeCurrent(number);
        return retval;
    });
```

When I try to input numbers the code doesnt work neither does the validation.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change your code to this?

```
$('#input_box').bind('change'
...
```

If as I think your input_box is a text input you should be able to detect changes in its content by checking for the event "change".

Comment: Yes ....I tried...I also tried keypress events but it doesnt work at all....even the breakpoints and alerts arent happening on debugger

Comment: @user3595524 What if you replace bind with "on" ?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: @user3595524 Another common error is to import incorrectly jQuery. Are you sure it is loaded?

Comment: Jquery is loaded and i tried on event as well...it doesnt work....does it have to do anything with event priority?

Comment: I just noticed that you are binding twice the same event to the same dom element... That's something that won't work. Also: at the end of your functions you are returning a value... but that value won't go anywhere as you coded it!

Comment: Was your idea to fill in the textbox with whatever comes from retval? Or is it just true/false?

Comment: What i mean is that i'm not sure of what you would like to happen with your 2 functions there.. if the retval is false... what would you like to happen?